# How to capture the dynamic libraries used by a container?

Tags: linux, dependencies, containers, libraries, elf

I'm new to libelf, and I have two questions:

I know it is possible to use libelf to get the dynamic libraries required by an ELF binary. I would like to know if besides the name of the library, it is possible to obtain the path where they are located.

I would also like to know if it is possible to get information from the dynamic libraries used by programs running inside a container, without having to run libelf inside the container.

Comment: Are you looking for the output from `ldd your_binary` or something else?

Comment: @EmployedRussian Yes, I look for the ldd return, but I need it in a c code, to I get all results in execution time when my code are looking for the various containers are made. This a thing in kernel level I think.